# An expression similar to "frame of reference"

Tags: expressions, mathematics, comparisons

I am trying to explain a mathematical point that is used for comparison such that all values are compared to it, like a "frame of reference". I've also thought of "pivot of comparison". Are any of these two correct or is there a better expression for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or how about a [***benchmark***, defined as:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/benchmark)

> A standard by which something is evaluated or measured.
>
> A reference point.

Answer (score 3):

How about ***reference point*** ...

> *noun*
>     a basis or standard for evaluation, assessment, or comparison; a criterion.
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reference%2Bpoint)