# What's the term for the left hand side of a comparison operation?

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics, comparisons, computing

I believe the right hand side of a comparison (i.e. the thing being compared to) can be termed a 'comparand'. Is there a word that can be used for the the left hand side of that equation? I.e. the thing that we're comparing?

Comment: "comparand" has no significant currency (it's not in OED). But if you're prepared to use it at all, I see no reason why it shouldn't be applied to the terms on *either* side of the "equals" sign *(**=**)* of an equation (or either side of other comparators, such as **<, >=, GT**, etc.).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is correct as usual, both operands (<- note!) to a comparison are termed *comparands*, but for fun, if you wanted to coin a plausible-but-technically-incorrect term to distinguish one side from the other, you could pattern them after the pairs augend+addend,  minuend-subtrahend, multiplicand*multiplier, dividend/divisor, and name them comparand<comparor. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] And even though we're playing "make stuff up as we go along", I'd only recommend using the non-symmetric terms for non-commutative comparitors like `<` or `>`, as even in persnickety texts that still use *subtrahend*, often name both arguments to the commutative operator `+` *addends* and the arguments to the commutative operator `*` *factors* (because they're equal in status and therefore are *not* distinguished or distinguishable: swapping them around has no effect). So for `=` and `!=` I'd *still* recommend calling both operands *comparands*.

Comment: @Dan Bron: Not entirely correct. I knew as I wrote it that I was on shaky ground calling those things ***comparators***, but ***operators*** had temporarily slipped my mind (besides which I really wanted to use a form reminiscent of ***comparand***, even though my browser keeps doggedly underlining that one! :)

Comment: If you're talking about English grammar and semantics instead of mathematics, then the usual term is _focus_ for the thing being held up for comparison, and _baseline_ for the thing being used as a standard for comparison. Baseline propositions (or their predicates or anaphors) are what is introduced by _than_ in comparative constructions; that is the only occurrence of _than_ in English, and its presence identifies a construction as comparative.

Comment: @JohnLawler do you know where those terms are mostly used?

Comment: @Ooker: In grammar, semantics, pragmatics, and linguistics generally. If this is a question about English and not mathematics, that is.

Comment: @JohnLawler I actually want to learn more on the linguistic perspective on analogy!!! As I don't think this question specifically asking only on math related fields, can you make it an answer?

Comment: Read Lakoff and Johnson's _Metaphors We Live By_ for the short answer on analogy.

Comment: Please provide an example of a ***comparison operation*** and a reference for ***comparand***.

Comment: related (talking about a point in stead of a value, but the answers include several possible adjective or adjective-phrase candidates): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111526/an-expression-similar-to-frame-of-reference

Comment: In metaphors (take the simple example _John has certain properties that bring to mind a tiger / John is like a tiger / John is a tiger_ / etc) (yes, the simile etc is still a metaphor) the thing one wishes to find a comparison for ('John' here) is the **tenor** and the essentially unrelated thing one chooses to depict properties of the tenor (['a / the'] tiger) is the **vehicle** [[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/art/tenor-literature)]

Comment: This question presupposes that comparing two things is an **asymmetrical** relationship, i.e. that one starts by focusing on one thing and then tries to explain something about it by comparing it to something else (in which case *comparand* would be a good term for the **'left'** side, that is, for the item one starts with). Comparisons are often like that, but **not always**: sometimes one takes two things simultaneously, considers them on a par, and compares them to each other in a way that makes the relationship symmetrical.

Answer (score 5):

Most of the discussion relating to this subject is found in a computer science/programming context, where the "direction" or "non-commutative properties" of a comparison operation are more obvious. One of the expressions (the left-hand expression, for example) could call a function that would modify a variable included in and affecting the evaluation of the other expression, making the order of evaluation an important issue (this is true of other arithmetic operations too: see [Word for the number being added-to OR subtracted-from another number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171807/word-for-the-number-being-added-to-or-subtracted-from-another-number) on ELU, mentioning the use of ***lhs*** and ***rhs***, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803844/word-for-the-number-being-added-to-or-subtracted-from-another-number on math.se for a one-off turned two-off of ***loperand*** and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579421/often-used-seldom-defined-terms-lvalue on SO)

One option, very general to be sure, is to call the objects on both the right and the left **comparison operands**.

(from [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)) (emphasis added):

> Arithmetic comparison operators
>
> If the **operands** have arithmetic or enumeration type (scoped or unscoped), usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both **operands** following the rules for arithmetic operators. The values are compared after conversions

And citing Joe Celko's *SQL for Smarties (Fourth Edition)*,[sciencedirect.com](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/comparison-operator) says (emphasis added):

> The comparison operators are overloaded and work for , , and  data types. They return a logical value of TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN where the values TRUE and FALSE follow the usual rules, and UNKNOWN is always returned when one or both of the **operands** is a NULL.

If **values** that don't need evaluation are provided, the comparison operators don't care which end you start comparing at as long as you respect the operator (as FumbleFingers pointed out in a comment). That is, **a < b** could be read "*a* is less than *b*" or "*b* is greater than *a*".

Or in one word, **comparands** (if you don't mind [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparand)):

> (linguistics, computing) A thing to which something is compared

Or **arguments**, calling out the right or left hand one, like at [http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node42.html](http://cs.union.edu/%7Estriegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node42.html) (emphasis added):

> Moreover, they force both their right-hand and left-hand **arguments** to be evaluated

Again, the comparison operator doesn't care where you start comparing; you would need some other way to indicate that one of the objects is the "benchmark", "standard" or "subject" (a few un-referenced suggestions from [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/word-for-things-which-something-is-compared-to.3335423/)).

IBM calls them both "operands" and "comparands" at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzase/sc092540262.htm (emphasis added):

> If your arithmetic is a comparison (contains a relational operator), then the numeric expressions being compared—whether they are data items, arithmetic expressions, function references, or some combination of these—are really **operands (comparands)** in the context of the entire evaluation. This is also true of abbreviated comparisons; although one comparand might not explicitly appear, both are operands in the comparison. When you use expressions that contain comparisons in ILE COBOL, the expression is evaluated as floating-point if at least one of the comparands is, or resolves to, floating-point; otherwise, the expression is calculated as fixed-point.
>
> For example, consider the following statement:
>
> ```
> IF (A + B) = C or D = (E + F)
> ```
>
> In the preceding example there are two comparisons, and therefore **four comparands**. If any of the four comparands is a floating-point value or resolves to a floating-point value, all arithmetic in the IF statement will be done in floating-point; otherwise all arithmetic will be done in fixed-point.

Comment: Off-topic: Incidentally, you could also consider the option of comparing without using comparison operators: https://www.techiedelight.com/determine-two-integers-equal-without-using-comparison-arithmetic-operators/. The question would then become: "What to call the operand on the left hand of a _logical_ operator?"

Comment: Is this suggesting **lhs** in preference to **LHS**? It's hard to see which is more common, although you could check the standards for your favourite language.

Answer (score 2):

Let A be *the thing to be compared*, and B *the thing to compare*, that is:

```
A is like B
```

then according to the [structure mapping engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_mapping_engine) (SME), A is called **source** and B is called **target**.

> SME maps knowledge from a source into a target.

Say we have a sentence: "The hydrogen atom is like our solar system". The "hydrogen atom" is the source, "solar system" is the target.

In the [original paper of Gentner](http://groups.psych.northwestern.edu/gentner/papers/Gentner83.2b.pdf), A is called the **base**.

<sup>FYI: [Analogy - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy#Mathematics)</sup>

Comment: The link to the Gentner paper doesn't work. That aside, from your answer, I don't understand the relationship between a mapping of one set to another (for example) and a comparison. Would you mind explaining? I apologize if it's a dumb question -- I'm just trying to understand your answer.

Comment: No worry. I've updated the link. Say we have a sentence: "The hydrogen atom is like our solar system". The "hydrogen atom" is the source or base, "solar system" is the target

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have it backwards. B is the source and the transfer goes right to left.

Answer (score 1):

If "comparand" is *that which is to be compared*, then "comparator" would I guess be *that which it is compared to*.

I based that on "dividend" *that which is to be divided*, and "divisor" *that which divides*.

The word exists...

> **comparator**
>   1.2 Something used as a standard for comparison.
>   *‘even taking the most favourable comparator the company is about 20 per cent higher’*
>   [SOURCE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comparator)

Note: **comparand** is not in *OED*

Comment: Why is OED more important than other dictionaries?

Comment: Most math types would call them both "comparands".

Comment: In many decades of doing mathematics (if that's what the OPs' question concerns), I have never encountered the term *comparand*. Also, in the physical sciences, a *comparator* is an instrument used to compare one thing, usually a physical object, to another or to a specified standard. See, for example, [https://www.precisioncalibration.com/2017/03/25/what-is-an-optical-comparator/].

Comment: On the positive side, a different meaning of *comparator* appears to have currency in the U.K. Cambridge defines *comparator* as *an organization, activity, etc. that is used to judge the performance of another similar organization or activity*. In the U.S., we would call such an organization, activity, etc. a *benchmark* or a *standard*. This jives with the definition you've referenced.

Comment: @Ooker OED is recognised by virtually all linguists as the sine qua non of English language dictionaries. It is the best researched and vetted. It may not respond as quickly as some others do to new usages which may be worthy of inclusion in the lexis (Wikipedia contains more headwords), and doesn't list senses in order of currency (being a historical dictionary), but its filters are the best. It is peerless in research presented on words actually included. As is the case with all other dictionaries, its treatment of grammar would be better left to dedicated works.

Answer (score 1):

They are both from Latin.

***Comparandum***: "The thing to be compared"

and

***Comparans***: "the comparing thing"

Comment: Hello, 436. What are 'they'? Are your candidates actual words in the English lexis ... do they have reasonable currency? If they're just projections from Latin, with no currency, they're not acceptable as answers on ELU.

Comment: Perhaps this answer is arguing from Karl Popper, who used *explicandum* and *explicans* in an analogous sense. These appear to be relatively recent coinages, although older than Popper.

Comment: There are quite a few usable Latin phrases in academic English that people understand even if they are not in a dictionary and, therefore, technically not English.  The fact is "comparans" answers the OP's questions better than any other substitute.  Even if the ELU rejects it, that's the word I'd use.

Comment: *Definiendum/definiens* and *explanandum/explanans* are well established pairs of technical terms (which a fair number of of non-specialists may encounter in introductory-logic courses); anybody who is familiar with these terms is likely to 'get' the meaning of *comparandum/comparans*, even if they are not in a dictionary. This answer, however, appears to be a variation on what was posted before in the comments below the question, and that should have been acknowledged.

Answer (score -1):

You can also compare the **unknown** to the **known**.